# Basic React component rendering twice without any API data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render, rerender

On my localhost in my console I'm seeing my component being rendered twice, and no clue why. I'm not pulling in any APIs using componentDidMount, just a basic component with nothing in there. Is this expected?

When I'm pulling in API data I'm getting 4 re-renders in my console where I'd expect to see another re-render when using componentDidMount to update the state.

I've seen a lot of threads around relating to state updates causing re-renders, but unable to find anything covering something which seems this basic.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Testing from "./components/Body/Testing"

function App() {

  return (

    <div className="App">

      <Testing />

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Testing.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class Testing extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.counter = 0;
      }

    render() {

        this.counter++;
        console.log('render ' + this.counter)

        return (
            <div>Test</div>
        )

    }
}

export default Testing
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My console output is as follows...

[image: React console output]

Comment: Uh, what is `this.counter`? It's not props and it's not state... isn't that probably causing the re-renders? Instead of having that weird `count` variable, just use `console.count`.

Comment: No, it's not what's causing the re-renders, I put that in there to illustrate what's going on. I can take the constructor out and it does the same.

Comment: Show us how u r rendering the App ? Simple DOM Mount?

Comment: @Panther ..I've added my index.js, nothing special in there. Just as it was when I created the app.

I'll add, I've not been using React long :)

Comment: you should try removing the `Strict` mode and see if the same happens. This is an side effect of `strict mode

Comment: Awesome! Did the job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design when using Strict mode. Its React's "Detecting unexpected side effects" feature.

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

From the docs...

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> Class component constructor, **render**, and shouldComponentUpdate methods

So yah, React is double rendering your component to show you you're doing exactly what you shouldn't be doing (modifying counter in render).

Since React can't tell what you're doing in render it figures double rendering is the quickest way to get a buggy application into a bad state. Pretty nifty!